# I cannot upload local files on a website using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, file-upload

I would like to upload my local files on the website:

https://www.freeformatter.com/convert-file-encoding.html

To convert the encoding of the original files to shift-jis. However, my code does not successfully do so.

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://www.freeformatter.com/convert-file-encoding.html')
for path in x_paths[8745:]:


    input_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.CLASS_NAME, 'form-control')))
    input_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.CLASS_NAME, 'input_file')))
    input_file.send_keys(path)
    target_encoding = Select(driver.find_element(by.NAME, 'targetEncoding'))
    target_encoding.select_by_value('SHIFT_JIS')

    download_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.ID, 'convertBtn')))
    download_btn.click()

    sleep(3)
```

I got the error below in the line:

```
input_file.send_keys(path)
```

It did not work:

```
input_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.CLASS_NAME, 'input_file')))
```

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=119.0.2151.72)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF75A572602+60402]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF75A4F7352+253666]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A2C9AE3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A313E46]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A311CD3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A33BA8A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30D766]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30D60D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A33BDB0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30D766]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A355111]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A33B863]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30C585]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30B993]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A30CD14]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF75A7534A4+1161924]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF75A38E5F6]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF75A44B083+37459]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF75A442C4D+3613]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF75A7521E4+1157124]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF75A5016A8+295480]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF75A4FCB74+276228]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF75A4FCCA2+276530]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF75A4EFA91+222753]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE4DF4257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE4F84AA58+40]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Chrome, and It worked... I would highly suggest you that you should not use waits with variable and then use those variables for selenium processes. like you did.. You are using same variable on 2 different waits.

Anyways, This is my implementation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.freeformatter.com/convert-file-encoding.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "file")))
wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "file")))
file_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "file")
file_field.send_keys("file.xml")
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works.
I did not know I shouldn't define a variable when using wait. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as useful.. Thanks @Ten